# How do I blur a particular area of an image in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gaussianblur

The main idea is to obtain the UI design of the Canva website homepage. Here's the link: https://www.canva.com/en_in/

Steps that I followed:

1. I found no way to blur a background image, so I inserted an image within a `<div>` with an id="background".
2. And then modified the CSS of it as:

   ```css
   #background{
     position:absolute; 
     top:0;
     left:0;
     z-index:-1;
   }
   ```
3. Now I'll blur the image so that, when I hover my mouse over it, that particular part gets clear.
4. Obviously, when I hover over it, the entire image gets clear.
5. But the goal is to clear the area where the mouse pointer overs at.
6. I guess, we should make use of the Mouse event ClientX property to get the position of the mouse pointer and clear that particular co- ordinate.
7. But I'm clueless on how to code it.

Answer (score 3):

> https://github.com/thdoan/magnify

A simple way would to use magnify to zoom over the already blurred image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.zoom').magnify();
});
```

```css
img {
 -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnify/2.3.0/js/jquery.magnify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnify/2.3.0/css/magnify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="zoom" data-magnify-src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
```

Comment: Sometimes there's a "Script error." coming. Try playing with your snippet. Hovering, going out, hovering, going out of snippet, etc… I don't know exactly when it triggers.

Comment: think that script error is just chromes new error handling for javascript executed in an iframe i believe. "The "Script error." happens in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome when an exception violates the browser's same-origin policy - i.e. when the error occurs in a script that's hosted on a domain other than the domain of the current page."  it triggers when it hovers the image

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure JS solution that rely on `clip-path` and CSS variables, the idea is to duplicate the images to have one blurred and one not. Then we reveal the non-blurred one on the top:

```js
var image =document.querySelector('.blur');
var p= image.getBoundingClientRect();

document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
  /*Adjust the clip-path*/
  image.style.setProperty('--x',(e.clientX-p.top)+'px');
  image.style.setProperty('--y',(e.clientY-p.left)+'px');
}
```

```css
.blur {
  display:inline-block;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}
.blur:before,
.blur:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:var(--i);
}
.blur:before {
  filter:blur(5px) grayscale(60%);
}
.blur:after {
  clip-path: circle(60px at var(--x,-40px) var(--y,-40px));
}
```

```html
<div class="blur" style="--i:url(https://picsum.photos/400/200?image=1069)">

</div>
```

With this solution you can easily do the oppsite if you want to blur a part of the image on hover:

```js
var image =document.querySelector('.blur');
var p= image.getBoundingClientRect();

document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
  /*Adjust the clip-path*/
  image.style.setProperty('--x',(e.clientX-p.top)+'px');
  image.style.setProperty('--y',(e.clientY-p.left)+'px');
}
```

```css
.blur {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:50px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}
.blur:before,
.blur:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:var(--i);
}
.blur:after {
  filter:blur(5px);
}
.blur:after {
  clip-path: circle(60px at var(--x,-40px) var(--y,-40px));
}
```

```html
<div class="blur" style="--i:url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069)">

</div>
```